# Vaadin App: Show scrollbar(Left-Right) on bottom of browser when not in full screen

Tags: java, scrollbar, vaadin

In ever Vaadin app I've looked at including my own, if your browser is in non-full screen mode(Partially minimized), there is no horizontal scrollbar at the bottom making the app impossible to use without a full size browser window.

Many of my users have 2 browsers open at a time, each occupying half the screen so they need a horizontal scrollbar to use the app.

Is there a way to force the browser to show a horizontal scrollbar with a vaadin app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about forcing the scrollbar to displayed, but [Panel](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Panel.html) and [Window](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Window.html) classes implement the [Scrollable](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/terminal/Scrollable.html) interface, which allows them to be scrolled.

Just don't use a relative width and you will get the horizontal scrollbar. I believe you can also set Panel's width undefined and let the components inside Panel define the actual width.